# decode encoded UTF-8 json text in swift

Tags: json, swift, utf-8

I'm fetching some `json` data from internet with this code

```swift
facilitiesService.facilitiesServerDataJson(urlToFetch: url_, jsoncompleted: { () in
let responseData: Data =  self.facilitiesService.UpdateJsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let facilityDataListTmp = try decoder.decode([FacilityData].self, from: responseData)
```

which works fine for alphabet, but my `json` also contains japanese text so my output became like this

```json
nicopass.FacilityData(
tn_newsid: 999900001,
tn_midashi: "æºæã®å¤ã«ç¾ããç¥ç§ã®è¹ãã ã¼ã³ãã¦ããè¦ããå¹¸éãè¨ªããï¼è½å·®55mã§åå­£æãã®ç¾ããçµ¶æ¯ãæããåç"
```

As you can see, it works fine for alphabet, but Japanese became some weird characters.
Im able to decode it here from `utf-8` to normal text [>>link](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-decode)

But I would like to know how to decode it in the source code.

Comment: How does your json encoded? Is it create json string and then encode it's string?

Comment: yes, the above is all I have `url_` contains url to json page and fetched data has this format: `[nicopass.FacilityData(tn_newsid: 144377, tn_midashi: "ç¥åºåå³¶ã¨ãªãã¼ãã¯æµ·ã®çµ¶æ¯ãåºãã", tn_name: "åæµ·éç«ãªãã¼ãã¯å¬åãªã¼ãã­ã£ã³ãå ´ã¦ãã¨ããã©", tn_ktel: "0152-45-2277", tn_url: "https://www.and.or.jp/", tn_ido: 4.9880220633556, tn_kdo: 14.239526856306, tn_im1name: "144377_1.jpg"),`

Comment: Where do you get `UpdateJsonString`? Can you provide code before `jsoncompleted` is called

Comment: its part o bigger code snipped and I'm not able to paste it here. I was able to get the string from `facilityDataListTmp ` in loop, could you please tell me how to decode string from `utf-8` like on the site mentioned in the link above?

Comment: Can you try [JSON lib](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). I believe your server does not encode anything. They just send data and you just need to read json normally `let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is you're converting the String with UTF8:

```
let responseData: Data =  self.facilitiesService.UpdateJsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
```

I created a playground file to test the encoding/decoding of Japanese and French alphabet and it works correctly.

```
import UIKit

// the text you want to encode/decode
let myChars = "星空観察に最適なロケーション. Also other chars. Même du Français écrit par un Brésilien."

// your json node represented as a Struct
struct MyContent: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let content: String
}

// your data
let myContent = MyContent(id: 1, content: myChars)

do {
    // we encode the content, the encoded variable here would be the data you would get from your webservice.
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(myContent)
    
    // we decode your data without using any encoding type
    let val = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyContent.self, from: encoded)
    
    // the content printed is correctly presented.
    print(val.content)
    
} catch {
    // should not get any error, but just in case.
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

// version using a String as a starting point

let jsonString = """
{
    "id": 1,
    "content": \"\(myChars)\"
}
"""

print(jsonString)

if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        // we decode your data without using any encoding type
        let val = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyContent.self, from: data)
        
        // the content printed is correctly presented.
        print(val.content)
        
    } catch {
        // should not get any error, but just in case.
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

I updated the playground so you can better visualise all these conversions.

Reviewing the bit of code you posted, I see you have this **self.facilitiesService.UpdateJsonString** which is a String, usually when we make a web service request we get the result as Data, so I would say that data has already been decoded. I would advise you to check how it's done. There could have been something like *String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)*, maybe you should modify this UpdateJsonString variable to be Data rather than a String. So you avoid one operation.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just dont know how to convert the code I have with the `in` statement to yours `myContent ` to fit it to the code you provided.  I cant just delete the part `(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!` and leave it as `Data`, because it throws an error

Comment: @KoperaMarcel I updated my response, check it out.